# Crop manually an image

Tags: python, opencv

I am using python in OpenCV and I need to crop and image with a square of (40x40), but I need to place the square manually on the part of the image that I want to crop.
Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the user for the top point of the rectangle and then crop  the image accordingly.

```
... // ask top point (x,y)
define int WIDTH = 40;
define int HEIGHT= 40;
// cv2.rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]])
cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
crop_img = img[x:y, WIDTH:HEIGHT] # Crop from x, y, WIDTH , HEIGHT
...
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that the user does not know the top point of the recantgle, unless I can find a way of allowing them to select that point when visualizing the image...

Comment: You'll have to create a mouse event and store the points coordinates.
See: http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php

Comment: I got it! Thanks :)